# Checking if Two Different Config Specs Select Exactly the Same Element Versions

Tags: clearcase

I have two similar but different config specs that I believe should select all of the same element versions. How can I most easily check if this is the case?

Comment: I would suggest to list all files view by both config specs, and compare the lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two dynamic views, each one with their own config spec:

```
cleartool setcs -tag aViewTag yourConfigSpecFile
```

You can then compare the result of:

```
cleartool ls
```

(in both views)

A `cleartool ls` display the exact version found in each view.

Even better, using [fmt_ccase](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm):

```
# unix
cleartool find . -exec 'cleartool desc -fmt "Version: %n\n" $CLEARCASE_XPN'
#windows
cleartool find . -exec "cleartool desc -fmt \"Version: %n\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""
```

That will list all the selected versions, and you can redirect the output in a file, one for each view.
Then the comparison is trivial.

Comment: How would I exclude view-private files?

What must CLEARCASE_XPN bet set to?

What would the Cygwin syntax be?

Comment: @Dave try the unix syntax. The find command will set `CLEARCASE_XPN` for you, for each element found.

Comment: @Dave and yes, it will exclude private file, plus you can use a dynamic view made just for that purpose (in which you have no private file anyway).

Comment: I found this answer helpful but needed to make a small change to obtain full version information in the listings: change CLEARCASE_XPN to CLEARCASE_PN.